# Which components need replacing in my Frigidaire oven?

Tags: repair, oven, troubleshooting

I've been having gradually worsening trouble with my electric double wall oven (Frigidaire model GLEB27T8ABA) for some time.  The problems have become intolerable, and I intend to attempt a repair.  Inasmuch as I think one or more of the oven's control boards are to blame, and these are expensive and probably non-returnable, I hope someone will evaluate the symptoms and my diagnosis.

Symptoms, roughly in order of appearance:

- The two oven lights normally do not work, but occasionally one or both briefly do.
- We have occasionally had alarms and oven codes in the past, but we are not currently seeing any.  A repairman that we had look at the problem cleared the code by power-cycling the unit, and we have done the same a couple of times since.  I have poor records on the specific code, but I think it was an F0.
- We have observed the top oven failing to heat to the set temperature, yet reporting that it was at temperature.  We subsequently had the top oven heat perfectly normally, as judged by an oven thermometer.
- The oven door latches, one or both, sometimes engage by themselves.
- The exhaust fan sometimes turns on and off by itself.
- The top oven now no longer turns on at all.

Overall, new / recurring symptoms seem to have been associated with running one or both ovens, and perhaps more so with running them longer and / or at higher temperature.

The oven has three control boards -- one main "timer" board that seems to house all the control circuitry, and a separate relay board for each oven.  I am pretty confident that the timer board is faulty (but any contrary opinion on that is welcome).  The main concerns that I hope an answer will address are

1. whether one or both of the other boards may also be faulty,
2. whether the symptoms suggest a fault in any of the other wiring or components as a possibility, and
3. whether I risk damaging a new timer board if I install it into the system alongside faulty components (else I can tackle the problems incrementally).

Comment: Have you located the troubleshooting guide and wiring diagram that are usually found behind the keyboard/display panel? It will have all the trouble codes and their fault indications listed. On my electric double oven I had to replace the main circuit board after approx. 6 years, and the keyboard/display panel at 10 years.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, I have located a wiring diagram and "service data sheet" online, and believe it or not, I have the original manuals, but there are no diagrams or other documentation behind the control panel.  The fault codes I've found documented do concur with my diagnosis of a problem with the "timing" board.  With the diversity of symptoms, however, I'm hoping for some advice with respect to whether I should be looking for multiple failing components.